# Which SWIG typemap from C++ pointer to numpy array?

Tags: c++, python, arrays, numpy, swig

I would like to map in SWIG a C++ double * vec type with a numpy array, so i read these documentations :
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.interface-file.html , especially section "Common example"
and http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn18.

I don't manage to make understand to SWIG that (int len, double* ivec) is actually expected to be an (int, numpy.array), and not a numpy array ?, despite my use of numpy.i typemaps. I tried the following:

```
/* test3.cpp */

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


void abel(int len1, double* ivec, int len2, double* ovec)
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;

    return;
}
```

and

```
/*test3.h*/

#ifndef TEST3_H_INCLUDED
#define TEST3_H_INCLUDED
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void abel(int len1, double* ivec, int len2, double* ovec);

#endif // TEST3_H_INCLUDED
```

and I links the C++ types **(int size,double* ivec)** with the numpy.i typemap **(int DIM1, double* INPLACE_ARRAY1)**, juste like in the scipy doc

```
/*test3.i*/

%module Amod

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "test3.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
import_array();
%}

%apply (int DIM1, double* INPLACE_ARRAY1) {(int len1, double* ivec), (int len2, double* ovec)};

%include "test3.h"
```

I compile as explain in docs with :

```
swig -c++ -python test3.i
g++ -fPIC -c test3.cpp
g++ -fPIC -c test3_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.7
g++ -shared test3.o test3_wrap.o -o _Amod.so
```

I can import Amod in python without problem but :

```
>>>import Amod as ab
>>>import numpy as np
>>>a = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0])
>>>ab.abel()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: abel() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)


>>>ab.abel(a,a)
Hello


>>>ab.abel(3,a,3,a)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: abel() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
```

What was wrong ? Why the integeres arg disappeared ? I feel like I miss something important.

Thanks a lot, I tried to minimize my code as much as i could for this question. I am a newcomer here, don't hesitate to tell me how activate the color code to make it more readable.

Comment: That's the whole point of the typemap... You pass in a single Python object (the numpy array), and it converts it into a number of items and a data pointer that you can use in C++. SWIG is passing to your function `a.size` and `a.data` instead of `a`.

Comment: @Jaime 
Ok thanks, so actually everything work fine ! I didn't understand that the int standing for the array size was expected to disappear from the arg list, but it makes sens actually ! Sorry useless post.